# Jmeter - Response time by resource type

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to test a web page. Obviously it has css, images, js etc.  How can I group the response times by css,js and images so that I can clearly see the response time broken by resource types.

Answer (score 0):

You pose an interesting question.  The listeners in  JMeter show what's at the sibling/child level.  Therefore, instinctively, if you want just one type of resource in a given report, you'd need to put all the requests in a single controller and give that controller a listener.

You can get around restructuring your test by renaming your samples in a consistent manner.  Something like: "CSS - actual request name".

Then, using Aggregate Report, you can copy the results into a spreadsheet, sort by name, and get your metrics that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use parallel controller to group the type of static files, ajax, etc. And use a transaction controller to group the page you would like to request, under the transaction controller you can add the parallel controller as hierarchy.